# XCode4, Mac OS X, xxx-Info.plist does not exist

Tags: macos, xcode4

Compiling my project fails because xxx-Info.plist cannot be found.  Indeed, that file does not exist on my computer.  The project has other targets, and they have their version of the file, and it's found, and they build.  I've tried to scour the targets for differences, but I don't see any.

Shouldn't Xcode be generating this file?  How can I induce it to do so?   Also: InfoPlist.strings does not exist, and xxx-Prefix.pch does not exist.  By "does not exist" I mean "does not exist".  I don't mean "The file is there, but Xcode can't find it."  This is not an iOS project.  Thanks.

Comment: [edit]  I deleted the offending target and built a new one, and everything seems to work.  Building new targets is something that I avoid if I can because there are so many settings that I might get wrong.

Answer (score 1):

These are specified in each target's build settings. Select the project in the Project Navigator, then select the target, choose the Build Settings tab, and make sure the correct PLIST and PCH files are specified. You can use the settings' search field to find the settings.

Comment: ... but please notice that those files **do not exist** on my computer.  At least they don't exist by any name that I can recognize.  I can't tell Xcode where to look for them.  Shouldn't they be automatically generated by Xcode at some point?

Comment: Ah. I see. They are generated when targets (that use them) are created. A .app target should definitely be creating .pch and xxx-Info.plist. Note: non-bundle targets won't automatically get an xxx-Info.plist (but they *can* be used and embedded). Most targets, however, should get a .pch file.

Comment: Also, there was a bug on earlier Xcode 4 versions that would not reliably rename everything if you'd rename a project or target. Could this be the case with your project?